# Why does C's strcpy fail with doubly indexed arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, cstring, strcpy

The following code seems to segfault and I cannot figure out why.

```
#include <string.h>

static char src[] = "aaa";

int main()
{
   char* target[2] = {"cccc","bbbbbbbbbb"};
   strcpy(target[1],src);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What will memory look like before the `strcpy`? What will it look like afterwards?

Comment: look up what strcpy() does exactly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `target[1]` is a pointer to `"bbbbbbbbbb"` and you are not allowed to modify string constants. It's undefined behaviour.

It's no different to:

```
char *x = "bbb";
x[0] = 'a';
```

I think you *may* be confusing it with:

```
char x[] = "bbb";
x[0] = 'a';
```

which *is* valid since it creates an array that you are allowed to modify. But what yours gives you:

```
char* target[2] = {"cccc","bbbbbbbbbb"};
```

is an array of pointers, all of which point to non-modifiable memory.

If you were to try:

```
char t0[] = "cccc";
char t1[] = "bbbbbbbbbb";
char* target[2] = {t0, t1};
strcpy(target[1],src);
```

you would find that it works since `target[1]` now points to `t1`, which is modifiable.

Comment: Then why does this work? `#include <string.h>

static char src[] = "aaa";

int main()
{
   char* target = "bbbbbbbbbb";
   strcpy(target,src);
   return 0;
}
`

Comment: @confused: If that works, it's purely by accident. It's _still_ undefined behaviour and you shouldn't do it, since _anything_ may happen - sometimes the "anything" may be that it just works, but switching to a different system, or compiler, or compiler flags or even running after 9pm or on a blue moon may cause your code to crash. For example, that _exact_ code causes "Segmentation fault" on my Ubuntu 10.04 box.